# hypcap not working with floatrow

Tags: hyperref, captions, floatrow

I'm trying to get hyperlinks for figures work properly. I mean clicking on a link should take me to the figure (not the caption). It doesn't seem to be working with floats in floatrow. No matter where I put the \capstart, The links always point to the caption instead of figure. The MWE is here.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage[hypcap]{caption}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \begin{floatrow}[3]
    \capstart\hypertarget{fig:1}{\ffigbox{\rule{3cm}{3cm}}{\caption{Click This Link}}}  
    \capstart\hypertarget{fig:2}{\ffigbox{\rule{3cm}{3cm}}{\caption{Click This Link}}}
    \capstart\hypertarget{fig:3}{\ffigbox{\rule{3cm}{3cm}}{\caption{Click This Link}}}
  \end{floatrow}
\end{figure}

\clearpage
\newpage

\section{\protect\hyperlink{fig:1}{Section A}}
\lipsum
\section{\protect\hyperlink{fig:2}{Section B}}
\lipsum[2]
\section{\protect\hyperlink{fig:3}{Section C}}
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

Surya

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following example uses the anchor by `\caption` via `\label{<label>}` and links it via `\hyperref[<label>]{...}`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \begin{floatrow}[3]
    \ffigbox{\rule{3cm}{3cm}}{\caption{Click This Link}\label{FIG:1}}
    \ffigbox{\rule{3cm}{3cm}}{\caption{Click This Link}\label{FIG:2}}
    \ffigbox{\rule{3cm}{3cm}}{\caption{Click This Link}\label{FIG:3}}
  \end{floatrow}
\end{figure}

\clearpage
\newpage

\section{\texorpdfstring{\hyperref[FIG:1]}{}{Section A}}
\lipsum
\section{\texorpdfstring{\hyperref[FIG:2]}{}{Section B}}
\lipsum[2]
\section{\texorpdfstring{\hyperref[FIG:3]}{}{Section C}}
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

**Further remarks**:

- `\hyperref` will not work in bookmarks, thus `\texorpdfstring` disables it for the bookmarks.
- The example uses uppercase label names to avoid trouble with the link in head lines with uppercase letters.